# Databinding an in-memory Bitmap to an ImageView

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-databinding

I have a bitmap in-memory (downloaded from a server application via a proprietary TCP/IP protocol stack) which I want to bind to an ImageView.  I am able to manually bind the image using setImageBitmap, however; if I use the databinding library to bind other controls, the image does not display.  How can I use the databinding library to bind to a property that contains the Bitmap object?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a `@BindingAdapter`, something like:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:imageBitmap")
public static void loadImage(ImageView iv, Bitmap bitmap) {
   iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Then, in your layout, your `ImageView` would have `bind:imageBitmap="@{...}"`, where `...` would be a binding expression that returns your `Bitmap`.

Comment: I am trying to load imageView using picasso in an item inside recyclerView using databainding, apparently when I scroll the up and down the images load again even if they were loaded a minute again, https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial101/tree/master/app/src/main/java/data/binding/list/activities/three

Answer (score 6):

You can use `android.databinding.adapters.ImageViewBindingAdapter`, which is included in the data binding library.

In your view model, or whatever is bound to your view, implement a method such as this:

```
@Bindable
public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

And in your `ImageView`, add something like this:

```
android:src="@{viewModel.drawable}"
```

Obviously, the `viewModel` variable must have been declared in your layout.

This works because `ImageViewBindingAdapter` has this method:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
public static void setImageDrawable(ImageView view, Drawable drawable) {
    view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```